# HTML5 videos in Webview showing blank preview after replacement of Android Webview by Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, webviewchromium

It was showing all videos as it should before the update of my device firmware.
But now all videos showing a blank image instead of the initial frame loaded,
When I disable Chrome from my apps, Videos again starts working as it re enabled the old Android `WebView`.
Strange is when i open my url in chrome browser it is showing correctly.

Should I change anything in my `WebView` settings to make it work again?!

What I Expect is - 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjuIo.jpg)

What I am getting is - 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/meSvA.jpg)

My Webview Implementation in Dev options - 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXNfd.jpg)

Comment: Anybody please help

Comment: There isn't enough information here about what you were doing before and the current state for anyone to help. Best would be to create a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as there are a number of things that could have gone wrong/become different between test environments.

Comment: Can you test if the preview of the html5 video in this link -https://codepen.io/caraya/pen/FckCd  is appearing or not in a Android 7.0 device webview ???

Comment: In Android 7.0, Google changed to use the Chrome Browser as WebView engine: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0#chrome--webview-together Check what are your WebView provider settings in Developer Options and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52142117/edit) your question with what versions of what providers are working/not working for you. Also realized that screenshot(s) of what you expect to see/don't see will be helpful

Comment: I have added screen shots of what i want and what i am getting. And also my webview settings. Please check